# GTK+: Move tree element to another parent

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I have a treeiter created with the `treeiter = self.devices_treestore.append(parent_treeiter, column_values_list)` call.

How can I move it to another parent (with the whole subtree it holds)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the new parent is at the same level of the tree, you could use `treestore.swap`, otherwise you may have to just remove all the rows in the subtree and reinsert them at the new position